# memory leak with opencv.js.. Page reload also increases the memory footprint by min 100MB

Tags: javascript, opencv

I am using opencv to get some image processing done.
They are able to do [CLAHE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_histogram_equalization) very fastly which am not able to achieve using a GPU too using WebGL.

But as I keep processing multiple images after loading it using HTML5 FileReader API, GPU memory gets increased and at some point , lets say after 20-30 images it crashes the GPU and throws a AW, Snap in Chrome browser.

Code :

`

```
var applyClahe = function(inputCanvas) {
    let src = cv.imread(inputCanvas);
    let equalDst = new cv.Mat();
    let claheDst = new cv.Mat();
    cv.cvtColor(src, src, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);
    cv.equalizeHist(src, equalDst);
    let tileGridSize = new cv.Size(8, 8);
    // You can try more different parameters
    let clahe = new cv.CLAHE(40, tileGridSize);
    clahe.apply(src, claheDst);
    //cv.imshow('canvasOutput', equalDst);
    cv.imshow('canvasOutput', claheDst);
    src.delete(); equalDst.delete(); claheDst.delete(); clahe.delete();
};
var applyAHE = function (inputCanvas) {
    let src = cv.imread(inputCanvas);
    let dst = new cv.Mat();

    cv.cvtColor(src, src, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);
    cv.equalizeHist(src, dst);
    //cv.imshow('canvasOutput', src);
    cv.imshow('canvasOutput', dst);
    src.delete(); dst.delete();
}
```

`

I use the above code and process the canvas every time a new image appears on the screen.

HTML Code :

`

```
<div class="inputoutput">
    <canvas id="tempImg" alt="No Image"></canvas>
    <div class="caption">
        <input type="file" id="fileLoader" name="file" />
        <button onclick="applyAHE(_canvas)">AHE</button>
        <button onclick="applyClahe(_canvas)">CLAHE</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="inputoutput">
    <canvas id="canvasOutput" ></canvas>
    <div class="caption">canvasOutput</div>
</div>
```

`

For CPU side there is a leak where simple page reload is increasing the memory footprint by 100 MB minimum.

Comment: I know this was a recent question but have you figured out the reason?  I'm playing around on local server after downloading a compiled opencv.js master file and just inserted it into my index page.  Using nodemon, the page auto refreshes on file changes and after a while, browser task manager shows the localhost tab at 1.5+ GB of memory...and VIM at 80+ percent CPU, even after I force quit all VIM instances.  Never encountered anything like this.  WebAssembly issue?

Comment: yes I managed to prevent multiple reloads for the page for now to get rid of these problems. But I will look for a memory cleanup solution where I will research continuously.

Comment: Do you mind sharing how you prevented multiple reloads and injections into the page?

Comment: I deleted my `inputCanvas` every time am done with the image . A simple `clearRect(0, 0, width, height)` will be enough and next time I receive a new image with new dimensions, I use drawImage(image, 0, 0)